# Bluetooth Magic Mouse disconnects

Tags: bluetooth, mouse

I have an iMac, now running Mountain Lion; about six months ago I started finding that the mouse would lose connectivity whenever I banged it, even lightly, on the mouse pad; I also got a couple of kernel panics while the mouse was disconnected. Usually it would reconnect within 20 seconds or so, but not always. I took it in to Apple; there were bluetooth service failures associated with the kernel panics. They upgraded me from Lion to Mountain Lion and said the mouse looked OK. Things were fine for a while, but now the mouse is failing again.

I have no way of knowing whether the mouse is hosed, the bluetooth connection sucks, or there's a hardware problem in my box. If it's the mouse, I'm happy to buy a new one, or a trackpad, but don't really feel like laying out the bucks if it won't solve my problem. Ideas?

system.log shows the following:

```
Feb  2 11:03:58 rogers_imac kernel[0]: [AppleMultitouchDevice::willTerminate] entered
Feb  2 11:03:58 rogers_imac kernel[0]: [AppleMultitouchDevice::stop] entered
Feb  2 11:04:00 rogers_imac kernel[0]: [BNBMouseDevice::init][75.19] init is complete
Feb  2 11:04:00 rogers_imac kernel[0]: [BNBMouseDevice::handleStart][75.19] returning 1
Feb  2 11:04:00 rogers_imac kernel[0]: [AppleMultitouchHIDEventDriver::start] entered
Feb  2 11:04:01 rogers_imac kernel[0]: [AppleMultitouchDevice::start] entered
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet is to see if you can borrow another BlueTooth mouse (or a keyboard) from somewhere so you can test to see if it is BlueTooth failure in the Mac or the Mouse.

Is there anything in your logs at the time of the failure? Those logs look ordinary - there are no processes dying or panics close to those times?

Comment: I added a dump from system.log above. Is there some other log I should be looking in as well?

Comment: No, nothing unusual near those times.